# GRUB Timeout Set to 0, Can't Access GRUB Menu Anymore

Tags: grub2

I'm using the newest version of Ubuntu, and I set my GRUB timeout to 0 and the default to start Windows. Now I can't access GRUB or boot Ubuntu. Holding shift does not work when the timeout is set to 0.

How do I boot into Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Hold down the 'shift' key as the machine boots. The grub menu should show.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live Ubuntu and role back what you have done. You need to change the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Be careful about the path, When you use a live CD partitions are not mounted by default.

for more information have a look at this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1650021

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/732216/271811) for how to set things up so that the GRUB boot menu is interruptible when timeout=0.